# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for command line argument

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, indexoutofboundsexception

I've this code snippet:

```
class CMD{
    public static void main(String[] s){
        String[] spt = s[0].split(".");
        System.out.println(spt[0]);
    }
}
```

To execute the program I'm using the command:

```
java CMD Test.java
```

I'm supposed the program should print `Test` but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
Why?

Comment: What argument are you trying to pass to your program?

Comment: Where do you get that exception? When assigning to `spt` or when printing afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're splitting on "." which means "any character" in regular expressions. So while "any character" can be a delimiter, your split returns no actual values. (I'm surprised it doesn't return either an empty string or several empty strings, but that's a different matter.)

If you escape the "." using a backslash (and then escape the backslash as it's in a string literal) it works:

```
String[] spt = s[0].split("\\.");
```

An alternative (massive overkill for this tiny program, but useful in real world apps) is to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and its [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class:

```
Splitter splitter = Splitter.on('.');
Iterable<String> bits = splitter.split(s);
for (String bit : bits) {
    System.out.println(bit);
}
```

Comment: your code works. Thanks! But I'm still not getting why was there `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? And why I need `\\\`?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: Are you aware that the argument to `String.split` is a regular expression? How familiar are you with regular expressions? How familiar are you with Java's string literal escaping? Basically you want a regular expression of just `\.` but in a Java string literal you have to write that as `"\\."`.

Comment: I've very little knowledge about regular expression. But I know about Java string literal escaping.

Answer (score 0):

use the following you will get your answer.

**java CMD "Test.java"**

Comment: No need to quote... `Test.java` does not contain anything worth quoting.

Comment: Did *you* try this? (It still breaks.)

Comment: no i am just giving the answer, according to me it will work.

Comment: still `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @user2320537: It doesn't. Try it rather than guessing.